# pass data from component to html in angular

Tags: angular, components

I trying to pass data from component to html in specific case :

i have in component method that get a id:

component.ts:

```
getId(){


this.id = 3; // example, i have in id number 3 (example)

}
```

component.html:

i have here a link url in `iframe`

```
<iframe width="1000" height="1000" src="http://....../watcher/ {{ here i want this.id}}" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

How i can pass this id in component.html?

Comment: does providing `.../watcher/{{ id }}` not working?

Comment: no. i thing i need to add <ng-container> but also not work

Comment: Make a dynamic src variable in your component.ts itself, and directly use it in the iframe src.

Comment: @SoumilKhandelwal how ? example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in your ts:**

```js
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

id = 100; // for instance

  constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public getUrl(id: number) {
    const urlSanitazed = `http://http.cat/${id}`; // Your url `http://.../watcher/${id}`;

    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(urlSanitazed);
  }
```

**in html:**

```
<iframe
    width="1000"
    height="1000"
    [src]="getUrl(id)"
    style="border: 0"
  ></iframe>
```